# Fill image url path dynamically and push to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am trying to capture the image path, that exists in database, and dynamically push to the variable URL. Every time I call the app the "new PesquisaEnqueteDetalhe().execut(url);", the application stops responding and closes.

I already re-written several times and still have not found where I am wrong. I have done similar scenarios in the same application. Could help me?

My java class

```
package com.clubee.vote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CarregaEnquete extends Activity {

String pid="1";
String url;
TextView txtNome;


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ENQUETE = "nome_votacao";
private static final String TAG_URL = "url_img_path";


private static String url_Insere_voto = "http://dev.clubee.com.br/dbvote/insereVoto.php";
private static String url_PesquisaEnquete = "http://dev.clubee.com.br/dbvote/pesquisaDetalhesEnquete.php";

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public String tipoVoto=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.carrega_enquete);

    new PesquisaEnqueteDetalhes().execute(url);

    int loader = R.drawable.loader;
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVotacao);
    String image_url = url;
    //String image_url = "http://clubee.com.br/imgs/vote_imgs/DilmaEdicao.png";
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);

    final Button btnVotoSim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSim);
    final Button btnVotoNao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNao);

    // evento de clique no botao Sim
    btnVotoSim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Button btnSim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSim);
            String tipoVotoS = btnSim.getText().toString();
            tipoVoto = tipoVotoS;
            new InsereVoto().execute();
        }
    });

    // evento de clique no botao Nao
    btnVotoNao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Button btnNao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNao);
            String tipoVotoN = btnNao.getText().toString();
            tipoVoto = tipoVotoN;
            new InsereVoto().execute();
        }
    });

}

class InsereVoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Antes de inserir e iniciar as açoes de background essa thread mostra o progresso
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CarregaEnquete.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Inserindo Voto..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        WifiManager wfman = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String macAddress = wfman.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
        if (macAddress == null) {
            macAddress = "Dispositivo sem endereço mac";
        }

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipoVoto", tipoVoto));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macAddress", macAddress));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Insere_voto, "POST", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // Voto cadastrado com sucesso
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Resultado.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                // Voto não registrado
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultadoFalho.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

class PesquisaEnqueteDetalhes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CarregaEnquete.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Buscando detalhes. Aguarde...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_PesquisaEnquete, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray enqueteObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_ENQUETE); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject enquete = enqueteObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoVotacao);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtNome.setText(enquete.getString(TAG_ENQUETE));
                        url = (enquete.getString(TAG_URL));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return url;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fffcfffa"
tools:context=".CarregaEnquete">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bkg_app" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoVotacao"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgLogo"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVotacao"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoVotacao"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSim"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SIM"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/votebtngreen_btn_default_holo_light"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNao"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NÃO"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/votebtnred_btn_default_holo_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output, on android studio, follow copied below

> 03-24 21:57:32.376  26927-26927/com.clubee.vote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.clubee.vote, PID: 26927
>       android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1154)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>               at com.clubee.vote.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:64)
>               at com.clubee.vote.CarregaEnquete$PesquisaEnqueteDetalhes$1.run(CarregaEnquete.java:182)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is right here:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // updating UI from Background Thread

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_PesquisaEnquete, "GET", params);
```

You are running this in the background section of the AsyncTask, but then you wrap it in a runOnUIThread() runnable.  That makes your AsyncTask pretty much useless since it is no longer running on a background thread.

You can probably remove the runOnUIThread() block and put all the necessary code to update the UI in the postExecute method

Comment: even making the changes, the problem persists. Nothing come on my mind yet.

Comment: Hello Gary, I made some modification on my code, and now it is running with no problem. Your suggestion helped me to resolve the problem, but I done a little diffferent.